# Get Id of item from dropdownlist in ASP.NET using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, dropdown

I have a dropdownlist in my project that get the value from SQL Server. Table in SQL Server has several columns and I select `MemberId` and `MemberName` from that. I want to show `MemberName` in the dropdown, but when I select an item, I want to get `MemberId`.

I do this like that:

```
string strsql1;
SqlConnection con1;
string strcon = "Data Source=ZAHRA\\SQLEXPRESS01;Initial Catalog=YekAye;Integrated Security=True";

con1 = new SqlConnection(strcon);

strsql1 = "SELECT MemberId,MemberName  FROM TbAye WHERE StatusMember = 1 ORDER BY MemberName";

SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(strsql1, con1);

con1.Open();

DropDownListAye.DataSource = cmd1.ExecuteReader();
DropDownListAye.DataTextField = "MemberName";
DropDownListAye.DataValueField = "MemberId";
DropDownListAye.DataBind();

con1.Close();
```

But this:

```
int SelectedMember = Convert.ToInt32(DropDownListAye.SelectedValue);
```

gets me the index of the selected item, not `MemberId` of it.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found What happened.
I write this:

```
int SelectedMember = Convert.ToInt32(DropDownListAye.SelectedValue);
```

in the page_load but I should write it in :

```
protected void DropDownListAye_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int SelectedMember = Convert.ToInt32(DropDownListAye.SelectedValue);
        }
```

Comment: It's usually a mistake to repost to the server and rebuild the entire page every time someone changes a drop down selection. Usually better to save this until the user is finally ready to complete a meaningful action.